Estou com um problema no meu código em relação a drop de imagens, onde não consigo pegar as imagens que vem dentro de uma pasta
Possuo um código feito em html, css e VUE, e está acontecendo o seguinte efeito: tenho uma área de drop onde posso adicionar uma pasta de imagens, selecionando a pasta que possui elas e quando confirmo todas as imagens aparecem na tela, mas quando arrasto a pasta e drop na área, ela me aparece vazia de arquivos, nao possuindo nenhum, mesmo sendo a pasta que usei de exemplo clicando e selecionando. Queria saber o motivo disso, pois nao entendo.
meu console.log mostra nada, tudo vazio
handleDrop(event) {
      this.isDragOver = false;
      const files = event.dataTransfer.files;
      console.log(files)
  },

FileList {0: File, length: 1}
meu drop area
<div
          id="dropArea"
          @click="triggerFileInput"
          @dragover.prevent="handleDragOver"
          @dragleave="handleDragLeave"
          @drop.prevent="handleDrop"
          :class="{ dragover: isDragOver }"
      >
          <p>Arraste e solte as imagens aqui ou clique para selecionar uma pasta.</p>
      </div>

meu input se tiver duvida
<input type="file" ref="fileInput" accept="image/*" webkitdirectory multiple style="display: none" @change="handleFileSelect" />
Como expliquei se eu clicar e selecionar a pasta inteira ele mostra todos os files que são imagens, mas se arrasta e solta nao mostra.

seu código espera que arraste imagens e não uma pasta, é preciso alterar o código para identificar que é uma pastas e ver os arquivos que tem dentro
